# Program Files Environment Variables giving different results in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, command-prompt, program-files

When I run the command `set programfiles` in the command prompt, I get

```
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

However, the following code in python

```
import os
print os.getenv("programfiles")
```

or

```
msgbox %A_ProgramFiles% and %ProgramFiles%
```

in Autohotkey

or

```
$env:ProgramFiles
```

in PowerShell

all results in `C:\Program Files`

I cannot understand why I'm getting different results for the Program Files Environment Variables in Windows

Comment: `ProgramFiles` environment variable differences between x32 and x64 processes.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the difference between a 32-bit and 64-bit application.

#### 32-bit cmd.exe (`%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`)

```
C:\>set programfiles
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

#### 64-bit cmd.exe (`%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`)

```
C:\>set programfiles
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

#### 32-bit powershell.exe (`%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`)

```
PS C:\> dir env:\programfiles*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ProgramFiles(x86)              C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles                   C:\Program Files (x86)
```

#### 64-bit powershell.exe (`%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`)

```
PS C:\> dir env:\programfiles*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ProgramFiles(x86)              C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles                   C:\Program Files
```